# Integrating Keycloak for Silent Authentication in Angular-SpringBoot Application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have developed an Angular-SpringBoot application, where users can log in through a custom login page in the frontend. After login, they are redirected to the dashboard page. Now, I need to integrate Keycloak for seamless authentication with an external API provided by a partner company. The goal is to allow users to automatically access the API without having to log in again, as they have already logged in to my application. The external API supports OpenID Connect (OIDC) and suggested using Keycloak for this integration.

I am looking for guidance on how to implement silent authentication with Keycloak in my Angular-SpringBoot application. Specifically, I need to know how to initiate the silent authentication process when the user accesses the dashboard and obtain a valid token from Keycloak to securely access the external API on behalf of the authenticated user.

Any assistance or code examples demonstrating the implementation steps for silent authentication with Keycloak in an Angular-SpringBoot application would be highly appreciated.

I tried searching online for related problems and solutions regarding the integration of Keycloak for silent authentication in an Angular-SpringBoot application. However, I didn't find much relevant information or detailed examples specific to my scenario.